# Java, Springboot, MongoDB extend SimpleMongoRepository (2020)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I've found many problems with this here in Stackoverflow.
But they are all in few years back. Hoping to find an updated solution.

I'm Extending SimpleMongoRepository in my own class to add some custom methods

Here is my code. **MongoHelper.java**

```
package com.customlibrary.mongodblibrary.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate; 
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Component
public class MongoHelper<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> implements 
CustomerRepository<T , ID> {


/**
 * Creates a new {@link SimpleMongoRepository} for the given {@link MongoEntityInformation} and 
                 {@link MongoTemplate}.
 *
 * @param metadata        must not be {@literal null}.
 * @param mongoOperations must not be {@literal null}.
 */
public MongoHelper(MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
    super(metadata, mongoOperations);
}

public void customMeth(){
    System.out.println("test");
}
}
```

Here is my code. **CustomerRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository<Customer, String> extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

}
```

And I already put this in my Main

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MongoHelper.class)
```

But there's a error showing up

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.customlibrary.mongodblibrary.service.MongoHelper required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' that could not be found.
```

Hoping Someone can give me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@NoRepositoryBean` instead of `@Component` for MongoHelper since MongoHelper is supposed to be a base class to be extended and not a bean managed by Spring

Comment: Thank you very much. It enlightened me so much.

Comment: This is the correct way to extend SimpleMongoRepository. Thanks for the question and the answer!